# Having tabs I want to draw a line on map and let it stay there all the time

Tags: android

I'm having some difficulty with drawing a line on a map. I'm basically drawing it etc. but when I select other tab and then come back to the "map tab" the line disappears. How can I prevent that so the line stays there all the time? Please can someone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [`Overlay`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html).